# Getting serial refusals for Schengen Visas

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, egyptian-citizens

So here's my issue. I am currently in a relationship with a girl in Germany and I am from Egypt. I have tried to apply for a visa to visit her with an informal invitation and stating all her details; however, I got refused because they thought that I have no intention of returning to my country despite providing them with an HR letter from my workplace that clearly states that I am coming back to Egypt to resume my job and a relatively big bank account and a return flight.

My colleagues advised that I should never apply to go meet someone in Germany unless she's my wife. They also said to go apply for France embassy instead and not to mention anything about visiting my girlfriend and apply for a normal tourist visa. I then applied for France and my papers were very solid and convincing, but the problem was that I am traveling alone. I received a phone call from the French consulate and they questioned my intentions of traveling alone and so forth and basically called me out on my bullshit. They also had a record of my rejection from the German Embassy.

At this point I am a bit frustrated because I feel like if you tell them the truth they won't accept you and if you lie to them, it's the same result. How am I supposed to go on about this when the result is always the same whatever you do, I need help. I applied 3 times in total at the moment (2x German Embassy and 1x French Embassy) and all of them were rejected for pretty much the same reason(s). It's very frustrating how strict they are even when you present the best papers to them. I didn't even get a chance to do an interview or anything.

What should I do?

Comment: `They also had a record of my rejection from the German Embassy` The database is shared across all Schengen countries and probably with other countries too. Why don't you fix this `thought that I have no intention of returning to my country` then ? Give evidence that you will return back. There are many question on this topic here.

Comment: I did provide "evidence" that I am coming back to my country by saying that I have a job and my job states that I am off on holiday and coming back to resume my work on day X. Like I can't convince them that I am coming back to my country if they just can't accept the most obvious reason why I will return. Also, having all this money in Egypt at the moment makes it incredibly hard to leave Egypt anyway because I can't just transfer all of it if I wanted to. So realistically, everything I presented should be enough evidence for me returning to my country.

Comment: The idea about meeting outside of Schengen area is not a bad one but u have to realize that I also want to go meet her family and so forth you know. Like I can't be just stricted to just seeing her outside of schengen region. I was originally planning on going on Christmas time as well so.

Comment: Now that you have made a falsified visa application, you are most likely out of luck.  It's probably time to make new plans that don't involve entering Schengen.

Comment: Is this an actual relationship or just someone met online and haven't spent any time with so far?  Honestly if it's a real relationship going forward, just get married.  You can then live together in either region, once you hire a competent immigration solicitor in the relevant jurisdiction. If it's "just an internet relationship" for better or worse yo'll never get a visa in a million years, you know?

Comment: I wonder if another try with a *Verpflichtungserklärung* would help or hurt.

Answer (score 8):

Look at it from the immigration officer's point of view, who has to assume that everyone is trying to immigrate there illegally:

1. You are a single young person.
2. You are in a relationship with a EU citizen.
3. You have no other compelling ties to Egypt.
4. You are applying for a temporary visit visa.

Now, what do you suppose is more probably, likely, or - to put it another way - what is it that you need to convince them that you are *not* likely to do?

A. Go on a visit to your girlfriend, stay there, and then come back. Okay, you may do this, but...

B. Go on a visit to your girlfriend, stay there, possibly get married, change to status, and then *not* come back.

Considering the large influx of immigrants from that area of the world, the current economic conditions - so it is your job to convince the officer that you plan on returning.

There is nothing illegal about the second point its just that you have to go through the appropriate channels for that - you have to apply with different kinds of documentation, etc.

Now, onto some specifics:

> So here's my issue. I am currently in a relationship with a girl in
>   Germany and I am from Egypt. I have tried to apply for a visa to visit
>   her with an informal invitation and stating all her details; however,
>   I got rejected because they thought that I have no intention of
>   returning to my country **despite providing them with an HR letter from
>   my workplace that clearly states that I am coming back to Egypt to
>   resume my job** and a **relatively big bank account and a return flight**.

First of all, your company's HR department cannot guarantee you will be coming back, how can they? I've had people go on short leave and then email a resignation letter.

Second, a "big bank account" is not a reason for someone to come back.

Third, a return ticket is required from all applicants for short visas.

So all those things are not really in your favor, except maybe if you have been employed for a long time at the same company - this can show a stable life here.

Now, what you CAN do - but this is not guaranteed to give you an approval is have your girlfriend provide an official affidavit of support, called a *Verpflichtungserklärung*.

This is a legal document - in the form of a bond - that guarantees your return and is provided by your host.

Please understand that if you are able to obtain this document **there are no guarantees that you will be granted a visa**, it is just that the Verpflichtungserklärung provides a more compelling reason for your host to make sure you return (because there is a substantial financial obligation/penalty if you don't).